# How to compute the product some of parts of two vectors

Tags: python, tensorflow

How can I compute the product sum of the first three elements of two vectors 
`A = [a1, a2, a3, a4, a5, a6]`and`B = [b1, b2, b3, b4, b5, b6] (i.e. [a1b1 + a2b2 + a3b3])`in python and tensorflow.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If it's just that simple do:

`sum([A[i]*B[i] for i in range(3)])`

This sums the products of the first three values with each other.

Hope this helps!

Answer (score 0):

```
import tensorflow as tf

tf.multiply(A, B)
```

in python you can use numpy

```
A = numpy.array(A)
B = numpy.array(B)
A*B
```

Answer (score 0):

Using built-in Python modules and functions, there are plenty of ways to do it.

Given below lists:

```
A = [1,2,3,4,5]
B = [4,5,6,7,8]
```

You can use the `zip` function to create pairs of elements from the two lists:

```
prod = list(zip(A,B))
print(prod)
```

Output:

```
[(1, 4), (2, 5), (3, 6), (4, 7), (5, 8)]
```

From there you can do it the following ways:

**1) Using list comprehension:**

```
res = sum(a*b for a,b in prod[:3])
print(res)
```

Output:

```
32
```

**2) Using `map` function:**

```
res = sum(map(lambda i: i[0]*i[1], prod[:3]))
print(res)
```

Output:

```
32
```

**3) Using `reduce` function from `itertools` module:**

```
from functools import reduce #Need to import only if you're using Python 3
import operator

res = sum(reduce(operator.mul, data) for data in prod[:3])
print(res)
```

Output:

```
32
```